# What does "one step away on each alignment axis" mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alignment

I'm looking at the improved familiar feat and it says that, does that mean if I'm a LG character I can pick a familiar who is LG, NG, LN, or N?

Answer (score 19):

## You Can!

If a character possesses an alignment that's Lawful Good, one step away on each axis means as a far away as Neutral for the Lawful component of Lawful Good, and as a far away as Neutral for the Good component of Lawful Good.

Here's the chart of [alignment steps](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/additional-rules#TOC-Alignment-Steps). While the text reads

> that diagonal "steps" count as two steps. For example, a lawful neutral character is one step away from a lawful good alignment, and three steps away from a chaotic evil alignment.

the feat [Improved Familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/improved-familiar) reads

> You may choose a familiar with an alignment up to one step away on *each* alignment axis (lawful through chaotic, good through evil).

Emphasis mine. Neutral is one step from Lawful on the L/N/C axis while Neutral is one step from Good on the G/N/E axis. Thus taking *both* steps along both axes allows a LG character to select a N improved familiar, despite the text's 2-step diagonal rule.

Comment: Note that being Neutral here lets you pick any familiar, as all creatures are within one step on both axes.